# Extracting text from postscript and/or creating overlays using python

Tags: python, postscript

I am trying to extract an address automatically from a postscript document that has been intercepted by redmon and piped to a python program.  I have gotten to the point where I can capture the postscript output (and write it to a file), but I am stuck at the extraction part.

Is there a good/reliable way of doing this in python, or do I need to run the postscript file through ps2ascii and hope for the best?

If there are tools in other languages that could do this I would be happy to evaluate them.

Comment: It depends a lot on how the postscript document is made. If you can give us an example, it may help to help you.

Comment: most likely the best approach will be to parse it yourself - the reason being you can utilise the surrounding code (and comments) to identify which strings are the address you need to extract. Start by looking at a few examples and looking for your target strings. Post an example with a bit of surrounding code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I commented on ps2ascii haveing a large footprint: here is an "80%" solution to extracting strings that appear literally in a postscript file using python.

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
 for p in line.replace('\\(','EscapeLP').replace('\\)','EscapeRP').split('(')[1:]:
  print p[:p.find(')')].replace('EscapeLP','(').replace('EscapeRP',')')
```

Note, finely formatted (kerned) postscript will often have strings split up into small pieces (even individual characters).  ps2ascii does a nice job of piecing them together for you while obviously my simple script will not.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in most cases just parsing the Postscript will suffice, since a Postscript document is a normal text file.

As a clarification: yes, I am aware that what a Postscript document displays is a result of a program written in the beautifully reversed or reversely beautiful language called Postscript. In most of the cases, however, it is sufficient to grep the program source. In some other cases text may be encoded as a curve or bitmap and there will be no way of extracting it short of OCR'ing the rendered output.

Bottom line: it depends of the type of information you would like to extract, and on the type of the postscript file. In my view, `ps2ascii` is a fine tool, and one way of solving the problem, but one that (i) will not guarantee a success (maybe slightly more than greping the source) (ii) to a large extent just strips operators and (iii) might, in some cases, lead to a loss of text.

Comment: A postscript docuemtn is a program file - and is readable as any  program. The text it contains may indeed be (and here your answer aplies) embedded in literal strings inside the program - but it may be encoded in various other ways as well.

Comment: Yes, that is why I wrote "in most cases". I have been using PS a lot in the days from before PDF was widely spread; clearly, you can have text encoded as a bezier curve or a bitmap, but very often you just need to grep it.

Comment: note ps2ascii has a large footprint. Unless you have or want ghostscript it wouldn't be my first line of attack.  +1 for the revised answer.. hate to see a '-' ..